# Dax Generate series based on 2 columns

Tags: python, php, sql, powerbi

I am trying to analyse energy consumption using rolling 365 day values and using assumptions and averages to get daily usage, the more reads the more accurate the assumptions become. I have the data set calculated but now its putting it into a analysable table.

Dataset

| MPAN | Current_Supplier | EAC | EAC_EFD | Days Applicable | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | TGPL | 96.7 | 22/05/2021 | 365 | 0.26 |
| ID1 | TGPL | 28009.9 | 26/11/2021 | 188 | 148.74 |
| ID1 | TGPL | 30771.2 | 23/05/2022 | 178 | 16.61 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 191.9 | 22/05/2021 | 365 | 0.53 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 217.9 | 26/08/2021 | 96 | 0.8 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 118.1 | 26/11/2021 | 92 | -0.56 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 38 | 25/02/2022 | 91 | -0.35 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 18.2 | 23/05/2022 | 87 | 0.3 |

*Column "0" is Daily usage*

So I have loaded it into Power BI as is and i want to generate a second table where I have column 1 showing the "MPAN" repeating as many times as the "Days Applicable" and column 2 showing the "EAC_EFD" (in a generate series with an increment of 1) and finally a "0" column (AKA daily usage) which will repeat like the MPAN as exampled below in an excel example with notes.

[image: Desired Output but in Power BI Table]

I've only been using BI for 2 month now so I'm fairly amateur at the whole thing so if there's a different or more efficient way of doing this let me know. Organising it in Python/PHP or a different Code/format is something I could be also interested in doing before I dump it to BI (assuming what I want to do cant be done) so its a wide open one.

Thanks
Ethan

Comment: Please post tables that can be copied rather than images.

Comment: Placing tables in markdown format, or giving a small example of the data in code, greatly increases the ease of helping you with your question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I've dropped in the sample data in markdown format.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a column that is a list of all numbers <= [Days Applicable] then "Expand to new rows" on the list, like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8nQxVNJRsjTTMwdSxmamQFLPyEwpVgcmZWRhYGCpZwlkGVpYgEgTCz1zE6XYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [MPAN = _t, EAC = _t, #"Days Applicable" = _t, Usage = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"MPAN", type text}, {"EAC", type number}, {"Days Applicable", Int64.Type}, {"Usage", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Day", each {1..[Days Applicable]}),
    #"Expanded Days" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Day")
in
    #"Expanded Days"
```

Comment: Thanks David this did work but my data extends past the capacity of excel's row limit.

Comment: Why is that relevant?